# For loop (inside while loop) is being ignored

Tags: c++, arrays, loops, matrix, getline

I have two for loops inside a while loop but when I execute the program, the while loop just becomes an infinite loop. Here is my code:

```
    while (!inFile1.eof()){

       for (int row = 0; row < 5, row++;){
            for (int column = 0; column < 5, column++;){

            getline(inFile1, fileData, (','));

            matrix1[row][column] = stoi(fileData);

            cout << matrix1[row][column];

            }
        }       
    }
```

I'm new to C++ so maybe I have made a silly error but I'd appreciate any help

Comment: I have been working on an answer and you deleted your previous question at the minute I was about to post a response.

Comment: Read about why `while (!inFile1.eof())` is wrong [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5605125/why-is-iostreameof-inside-a-loop-condition-considered-wrong).

Comment: I recommend you undo the removal of your previous question and we can continue on that one.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have stray commas in your `for` loops, which you should replace with semicolons:

`int row = 0; row < 5; row++;`

`int column = 0; column < 5; column++;`

Currently the *stopping condition* is `row < 5, row++`, which is the same as `row++` due to the way in which the *comma operator* works.

Eventually your `int` will overflow and then you're in *undefined behaviour* land.